# $.post doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

There are a couple of `alert()` calls in the jQuery which are showing up, but the `alert` inside the `$.post` does not seems to respond. I already tested the PHP code and it works fine. I think it is my `path`, but I already check them before.

```
<form id="login-form" method="post" class="form-inline" target="_top">
    <input type="text" tabindex="2"  id="username" placeholder="Username" name="email" class="inputtext">
    <input type="password" tabindex="3" id="userpass" placeholder="Password" name="pass" class="inputtext">
    <button tabindex="4" id="loginButton">Login</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#loginButton').click(function(e) {
        alert("start function");
        $.post('../php/login.php', {
            'username': $('#username').val(),
            'userpass': $('#userpass').val()
        }, function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
        alert("end function");
    });
});
```

```
<?php    
    require('config.php');

    $queryStmt = 'SELECT user_first, user_last FROM users WHERE user_name=:sqlIdName AND user_password=:sqlPass';
    $queryPrepare = $dba_connect->prepare($queryStmt);
    $queryPrepare->execute(array(':sqlIdName'=>$_POST['username'],':sqlPass'=>md5($_POST['userpass'])));
    $queryResult = $queryPrepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $queryPrepare->closeCursor();

    var_dump($queryResult);

    if ($queryResult == false)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;  
?>
```

My file structure is this:

[image: File Structure]

Comment: `$('#loginButton').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();`

Comment: `<button>` without `type="button"` will act as a submit button!

Comment: Also note that you need to `echo/print` from the `php-service`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `button` is actually submitting the form normally as you have not given it a `type="button"` attribute, nor are you using `preventDefault()` on the click event itself.

Regardless of that, it is much better practice to hook to the `submit` event of the `form`, not the `click` of the button. Try this:

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stop standard form submission
    $.post('../php/login.php', {
        'username': $('#username').val(),
        'userpass': $('#userpass').val()
    }, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

You may also want to return something other than a boolean value from your PHP code, as it will just be turned in to a single string response. JSON would seem to be the best fit for your case, check out the `json_encode` function.

Finally, note that you should always use `console.log` for debugging as it does not coerce data types.

Comment: I would add a handler if there is an error callback

Answer (score 1):

try this .its not exact ans may be the solution for it.

echo string in php server side something like this

```
if ($queryResult == false)
echo 'false'; 
else 
 echo 'true';
```

and then change your jquery to

```
function(data){
    if(data=='true')
     {
      alert(data);
      }
      else
      {
     alert(data);
     }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#loginButton').click(function(e) {
        $.post('../php/login.php', {
            functions: 'userLogin',
            username: $('#username').val(),                    
            userpass: $('#userpass').val()
        }).done(function( data ) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
    });
});
```